# Not able to populate two out of three of the birthday field components

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am able to insert the correct birthday in the database of what is selected in the dropdown menu. When the page reloads after successfully updating the database only the year portion of the birthday drop downs is showing up. Why is this the case? I am using the same simple logic for all three.

```
 // CONTROLLER

  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )
                    {

                            $data['main_content'] = 'account/edit';
                            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $birthdate = $this->input->post('month'). "-" .$this->input->post('day'). "-" .$this->input->post('year');
                            echo $birthdate;
                            $save_data = array(
                                'relation' => $this->input->post('relation'),
                                'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                                'birthday' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($birthdate)),
                                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                                'mylife' => $this->input->post('mylife'),
                                'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation'),
                                'hobbies' => $this->input->post('hobbies'),
                                'books' => $this->input->post('books'),
                                'music' => $this->input->post('music'),
                                'movies' => $this->input->post('movies'),
                                'quote' => $this->input->post('quote'),
                                'mycysticlife' => $this->input->post('mycysticlife'),
                                'medicines' => $this->input->post('medicines'),
                                'treatments' => $this->input->post('treatments'),
                                'PFTs:FVC' => $this->input->post('PFTs:FVC'),
                                'FEV1' => $this->input->post('FEV1'),
                                'mutation' => $this->input->post('mutation'),
                                'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
                                'myspace' => $this->input->post('myspace'),
                                'facebook' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
                                'blogspot' => $this->input->post('blogspot'),
                                'youtube' => $this->input->post('youtube'),
                                'url' => $this->input->post('url'),
                                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                                 );


                                    $query = $this->account_model->update_edit($user['id'],$save_data);
                            $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile';
                            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
                        }

                    }
                }

// VIEW

  <?php
                        echo month_dropdown('months', $user['birthday'])." ".day_dropdown('days', $user['birthday'])." ".year_dropdown('year', $user['birthday']);

                    ?>

// FORM HELPER

function month_dropdown($month="month", $top_month='' ) {

   $months = array(
        "choose"=>"Month",
        "Jan"=>"Jan",
        "Feb"=>"Feb",
        "Mar"=>"Mar",
        "Apr"=>"Apr",
        "May"=>"May",
        "Jun"=>"Jun",
        "Jul"=>"Jul",
        "Aug"=>"Aug",
        "Sep"=>"Sep",
        "Oct"=>"Oct",
        "Nov"=>"Nov",
        "Dec"=>"Dec"
  );

  $html = "<select name='{$month}'>";

  foreach($months as $key => $month){

      $selected = "";
      //this will match for selected value and set the selected attribute
      if( $key == $top_month ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }
      $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected>{$month}</option>";
  }
  $html .="</select>";
  return $html;

}

function day_dropdown($day="day", $top_days="") {
   $days = array(
        "choose"=>"Day",
        "01"=>"01",
        "02"=>"02",
        "03"=>"03",
        "04"=>"04",
        "05"=>"05",
        "06"=>"06",
        "07"=>"07",
        "08"=>"08",
        "09"=>"09",
        "10"=>"10",
        "11"=>"11",
        "12"=>"12",
        "13"=>"13",
        "14"=>"14",
        "15"=>"15",
        "16"=>"16",
        "17"=>"17",
        "18"=>"18",
        "19"=>"19",
        "20"=>"20",
        "21"=>"21",
        "22"=>"22",
        "23"=>"23",
        "24"=>"24",
        "25"=>"25",
        "26"=>"26",
        "27"=>"27",
        "28"=>"28",
        "29"=>"29",
        "30"=>"30",
        "31"=>"31"
   );

   $html = "<select name='{$day}'>";

   foreach($days as $key => $day){
      $selected = "";
      if( $key == $top_days ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }

      $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected >{$day}</option>";
   }
   $html .="</select>";
   return $html;

}

function year_dropdown($year="year", $top_years='') {
   $years = array(
        "choose"=>"Year",
        "1997"=>"1997",
        "1996"=>"1996",
        "1995"=>"1995",
        "1994"=>"1994",
        "1993"=>"1993",
        "1992"=>"1992",
        "1991"=>"1991",
        "1990"=>"1990",
        "1989"=>"1989",
        "1988"=>"1988",
        "1987"=>"1987",
        "1986"=>"1986",
        "1985"=>"1985",
        "1984"=>"1984",
        "1983"=>"1983",
        "1982"=>"1982",
        "1981"=>"1981",
        "1980"=>"1980",
        "1979"=>"1979",
        "1978"=>"1978",
        "1977"=>"1977",
        "1976"=>"1976",
        "1975"=>"1975",
        "1974"=>"1974",
        "1973"=>"1973",
        "1972"=>"1972",
        "1971"=>"1971",
        "1970"=>"1970",
        "1969"=>"1969",
        "1968"=>"1968",
        "1967"=>"1967",
        "1966"=>"1966",
        "1965"=>"1965",
        "1964"=>"1964",
        "1963"=>"1963",
        "1962"=>"1962",
        "1961"=>"1961",
        "1960"=>"1960",
        "1959"=>"1959",
        "1959"=>"1959",
        "1958"=>"1958",
        "1957"=>"1957",
        "1956"=>"1956",
        "1955"=>"1955",
        "1954"=>"1954",
        "1953"=>"1953",
        "1953"=>"1953",
        "1952"=>"1952",
        "1951"=>"1951",
        "1950"=>"1950",
        "1949"=>"1949",
        "1948"=>"1948",
        "1947"=>"1947",
        "1946"=>"1946",
        "1945"=>"1945",
        "1944"=>"1944",
        "1943"=>"1943",
        "1942"=>"1942",
        "1941"=>"1941",
        "1940"=>"1940",
        "1939"=>"1939",
        "1938"=>"1938",
        "1937"=>"1937",
        "1936"=>"1936",
        "1935"=>"1935",
        "1934"=>"1934",
        "1933"=>"1933",
        "1932"=>"1932",
        "1931"=>"1931",
        "1930"=>"1930"

   );

   $html = "<select name='{$year}'>";

   foreach($years as $key => $year){

      $selected = "";
      if( $key == $top_years ) {
          $selected = "selected='selected'";
      }

     $html .="<option value='{$key}' $selected >{$year}</option>";
   }
   $html .="</select>";
   return $html;

 }


// MODEL

  public function update_edit($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);

    }
}


thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at the code a little closer and I see this line and assume it's the one giving you the issues?

```
echo month_dropdown('months', $user['birthday'])." ".day_dropdown('days', $user['birthday'])." ".year_dropdown('year', $user['birthday']);
```

That variable should be returning a date in the format you saved it is so for me it would return 09-12-1967 which likely isn't legitimate values for your drop downs. You could explode that out then populate the drop downs like this:

```
$birthdate = explode('-',$user['birthday']);
 echo month_dropdown('months', $birthdate[0])." ".day_dropdown('days', $birthdate[1])." ".year_dropdown('year', $birthdate[2]);
```

That should work

Comment: I've posted the code. Thanks for the heads up. What do you suggest for a solution?

Comment: See edit, my original thought was wrong, I didn't notice those were in separate functions. You need to explode the birthday by the -'s to get the separate values.

Comment: So with what you sent it's just showing the day now. Which is confusing because you have it as 'days' and it's day. I fixed 'months' to 'month' but it's still not showing. I can't get year and month to show at all

Comment: I just copied what you had, the only thing I changed is what's populating them. Weird that it isn't populating the others, try echoing out the variables, including what it's returning as $user['birthday'] it's time to start tracking back and ensuring the data is saving/returning what you expect then you can make sure it populates the form correctly.

Comment: this is truly mind boggling as I have echoed each element of the explode array you created i.e. $birthdate[1] $birthdate[2] $birthdate[3] and they are all correct. The only one that is populating the form correctly is the day.

Comment: Just noticed a missing bracket after the month drop down, maybe that was the problem?

Comment: That's not it. That appeared right off the bat as it posed an error.